# find the min value in int array with C#

Tags: c#

how can i find the min value in int arry with c#

Answer (score 18):

With LINQ:

```
int min = theArray.Min();
```

note that this will error if there aren't *any* elements; check the `.Length` first (or alternatively, project to `int?`, but that adds overhead).

If you don't have LINQ available, then perhaps:

```
public static int Min(int[] arr) {
    switch (arr.Length) {
        case 0: throw new InvalidOperationException();
        case 1: return arr[0];
        case 2: return Math.Min(arr[0], arr[1]);
        default:
            int min = arr[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
            }
            return min;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does it mean? `case 2: return Math.Min(arr[0], arr[1]);` what are you doing in default?

Comment: Also what does it mean? `case 1: return arr[0];`?

Comment: @SaeedAlg - I'm checking the length of the array; if it case 1 item, then the min is obviously the first (only) item; if there are 2, then treat that as another special case *because we can do so conveniently* - otherwise we'll iterate over the array and *find* the minimum

Comment: You can do nothing with them, your default means you do this for array size of `1` or `2` there is no need to do this in `case` and you just need a simple if statement, but if you saying do it for readability it's acceptable.

Comment: @SaeedAlg - well, we need to check the Length *anyway*, so we may as well do something useful with the knowledge...

Comment: if (arr.Length > 0) do work else throw exception, there is no problem by your solution I just wonder why a good developer like you do this

Comment: @SaeedAlg - a switch, *especially* when based on consecutive integers from 0, is **incredibly** fast (it is a direct jump-table); so then the question would be: if I **know** that there is exactly 1 item - why would I loop? if I **know** that there are exactly 2 items, and I can compare directly, why would I loop? If you think there is something intrinsically *bad* or *incorrect*, please say what, exactly?

Comment: I tested it, a simple if to check for 0 length and then loop is even slightly (< 1%) faster so why go through the trouble of adding all the extra code.

Comment: @Doggett - fine, do it whichever way pleases you. Honestly,over-analyse much? The code as written will work fine and pass any (sane) test I can think of. Feel free to post the simpler version; I'll happily upvote it! But note also the first part of my answer... `.Min()`...

Comment: @Marc Gravell, I'd test it, your way is not faster in my PC.

Comment: @Saif - that is the first line in my answer; `theArray.Min()` **is exactly** `Enumerable.Min(theArray)`, since it is an extension method.

Comment: @Marc I'm sorry if I offended you in any way, I was just interested in seeing if a switch really wouldn't slow it down. Which it didn't, but it didn't speed it up either. So i was just saying might as well keep out all the extras.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote bellow to compare what i said by @Marc Gravell, the way I told is a little faster in my PC, and the linq one is slowest way, Also if you change the position of functions (in code) you will always gain a better performance with a version with `if`

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<long>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<long>>();

        dic["First"] = new List<long>();
        dic["Second"] = new List<long>();
        dic["Third"] = new List<long>();


        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            int[] array = GetRandomArray();
            Stopwatch stopWacth = new Stopwatch();
            stopWacth.Restart();
            int n1 = FindMin(array);
            stopWacth.Stop();
            long firstTicks = stopWacth.ElapsedTicks;
            dic["First"].Add(firstTicks);

            stopWacth.Restart();
            int n2 = AnotherFindMin(array);
            stopWacth.Stop();
            long secondTick = stopWacth.ElapsedTicks;
            dic["Second"].Add(secondTick);

            stopWacth.Restart();
            int n3 = array.Min();
            stopWacth.Stop();
            long thirdTick = stopWacth.ElapsedTicks;
            dic["Third"].Add(thirdTick);

            Console.WriteLine("first tick : {0}, second tick {1}, third tick {2} ", firstTicks, secondTick, thirdTick);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("first tick : {0}, second tick {1}, third tick {2} ", dic["First"].Average(), dic["Second"].Average(), dic["Third"].Average());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public static int[] GetRandomArray()
    {
        int[] retVal = new int[1000000];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            retVal[i] = r.Next(1000000000);
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public static int FindMin(int[] arr)
    {
        switch (arr.Length)
        {
            case 0: throw new InvalidOperationException();
            case 1: return arr[0];
            case 2: return Math.Min(arr[0], arr[1]);
            default:
                int min = arr[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
                }
                return min;
        }
    }

    public static int AnotherFindMin(int[] arr)
    {
        if (arr.Length > 0)
        {
            int min = arr[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
            }
            return min;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
// revised test by Marc (see comments discussion)
static class Test {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<long>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<long>>();

        dic["First"] = new List<long>();
        dic["Second"] = new List<long>();
        dic["Third"] = new List<long>();

        const int OUTER_LOOP = 500, INNER_LOOP = 500000;
        for (int arrSize = 1; arrSize <= 3; arrSize++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < OUTER_LOOP; i++)
            {
                int[] array = GetRandomArray(arrSize);
                Stopwatch stopWacth = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int j = 0; j < INNER_LOOP; j++)
                {
                    int n1 = FindMin(array);
                }
                stopWacth.Stop();
                long firstTicks = stopWacth.ElapsedTicks;
                dic["First"].Add(firstTicks);

                stopWacth = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int j = 0; j < INNER_LOOP; j++)
                {
                    int n2 = AnotherFindMin(array);
                }
                stopWacth.Stop();
                long secondTick = stopWacth.ElapsedTicks;
                dic["Second"].Add(secondTick);

                stopWacth = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int j = 0; j < INNER_LOOP; j++)
                {
                    int n3 = array.Min();
                }
                stopWacth.Stop();
                long thirdTick = stopWacth.ElapsedTicks;
                dic["Third"].Add(thirdTick);

                //Console.WriteLine("{3}: switch : {0}, 0-check {1}, Enumerable.Min {2} ", firstTicks, secondTick, thirdTick, arrSize);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{3}: switch : {0}, 0-check {1}, Enumerable.Min {2} ", dic["First"].Average(), dic["Second"].Average(), dic["Third"].Average(), arrSize);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public static int[] GetRandomArray(int size)
    {
        int[] retVal = new int[size];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
        {
            retVal[i] = r.Next(1000000000);
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public static int FindMin(int[] arr)
    {
        switch (arr.Length)
        {
            case 0: throw new InvalidOperationException();
            case 1: return arr[0];
            case 2: return arr[0] < arr[1] ? arr[0] : arr[1];
            default:
                int min = arr[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
                }
                return min;
        }
    }

    public static int AnotherFindMin(int[] arr)
    {
        if (arr.Length > 0)
        {
            int min = arr[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
            }
            return min;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Stopwatch` over a single iteration is not going to give a meaningful answer; also, this test only considers the `default` case (which to be fair is the most likely). And that array is **so** overwhelmingly large that any tests are *barely showing* any numbers from this choice of logic...

Comment: @Marc Gravell, I'd wroted it's average

Comment: (edit: my mistake, this is a 4.0 method) Also - `Restart` - is that an extension method of yours? I'm replacing (locally) with Stopwatch.StartNew()

Comment: @Marc Gravell, I think it's not meaningless, but if you think so whats your idea to compare them? I got the size of array to be big, so stopwatch shouldn't be meaningless, In all what's your suggestion?

Comment: No, I'm using `using System.Diagnostics;` in .Net 4, restart is not for me, @Marc Gravell, you should take care the assembly jumps, which is longer for my method

Comment: @SaeedAlg - there are two problems in the test; the array is so big that all of the time is spent running the **identical** code, the loop over the array. The bit you are contesting (the `switch`) is barely exercised **at all**. In fact, the *ideal* array size to check for a difference here would be `3`, since that would **minimise** the time spent in the identical code (thus highlighting the **different** code) - and even then we're only testing for *negative* impact of the switch - to test for *positive* impact you'd need to repeat for length 1 and 2 too.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, I don't know how to check array of size `1 , 2`, because I think all time spends for method calls. but size 2,1 is smallest number of possibilities at all.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I'm going to hack in my revised test after yours (it doesn't seem to warrant another answer); all it shows is that there is no noticeable difference - which is *fine* - but let's at least have that answer from a meaningful test...

Comment: @SaeedAlg - re the 1,2 - well my counter to that is that the test for *large* arrays is equally pointless... you **aren't getting any numbers for the code in question**

Comment: Numbers from my hacked test (release mode, console, etc) - all very close:
1: switch : 4857.764, 0-check 4992.75, Enumerable.Min 47196.438
2: switch : 5312.811, 0-check 5289.016, Enumerable.Min 53508.782
3: switch : 6253.37733333333, 0-check 5919.226, Enumerable.Min 59797.9706666667

Comment: all so close as *frankly* not worth all this analysis ;p

Comment: @Mark Gravell, This is my test in your situation: 1: switch : 8298814.446, 0-check 9660170.702, Enumerable.Min 54998559.278
2: switch : 9990758.141, 0-check 12815820.862, Enumerable.Min 60729784.856
3: switch : 14185835.456, 0-check 15739366.2486667, Enumerable.Min 66125055.7586, did you take care Enumerable.Min is near 10 time slower than other approaches?