# What's the fastest way to compare two arrays for equality?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, equality

I have two arrays of objects which are likely to have the same values, but in a different order, e.g.

```
{ "cat", "dog", "mouse", "pangolin" }

{ "dog", "pangolin", "cat", "mouse" }
```

I wish to treat these two arrays as equal. What's the fastest way to test this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can't guarantee that this is the *fastest*, but it's certainly quite efficient:

```
bool areEquivalent = array1.Length == array2.Length 
                     && new HashSet<string>(array1).SetEquals(array2);
```

EDIT:
SaeedAlg and Sandris raise valid points about different frequencies of duplicates causing problems with this approach. I can see two workarounds if this is important (haven't given much thought to their respective efficiencies):

1.Sort the arrays and then compare them sequentially. This approach, in theory, should have quadratic complexity in the worst case.
   E.g.:

```
return array1.Length == array2.Length
       && array1.OrderBy(s => s).SequenceEqual(array2.OrderBy(s => s));
```

2.Build up a frequency-table of strings in each array and then compare them. E.g.:

```
if(array1.Length != array2.Length)
   return false;

var f1 = array1.GroupBy(s => s)
               .Select(group => new {group.Key, Count = group.Count() });

var f2 = array2.GroupBy(s => s)
               .Select(group => new {group.Key, Count = group.Count() });

return !f1.Except(f2).Any();
```

Comment: It's like @Albin Sunnanbo answer may be you return two array are equals and they aren't equal.

Comment: @SaeedAlg: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Ani: an example is {"cat", "cat", "dog"}, {"cat", "dog", "dog"}. These arrays are not permutations of each other, but your expression returns true.

Comment: @SaeedAlg, @sandris: Thanks for that. Any comments on the workarounds I've suggested?

Comment: @Ani, nothing, but I compared some manner of linq with handwritten code and I see that linq is slowest, for example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119569/find-the-min-value-in-int-arry-with-c/4121721#4121721 I, compared the speed of linq `Min` which is slowest than hand written one.

Comment: @Ani: I think both approaches are correct, although sorting and comparing has O(n log n) complexity, as pointed out in djechelon's answer.

Comment: @sandris: In quicksort's worst case (sequence almost sorted already), the time-compexity deteriorates to quadratic. This is rare, which is why I emphasized "in theory". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: `SequenceEqual()` checks lengths, so you don't need to do that.

Comment: @Andikki: Yes, but the SequenceEqual is after the OrderBy, so the quick-fail check can help unnecessary sorting in many cases.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only reasonable way is to sort them and then compare.

Sorting requires `O(n logn)` and comparing `O(n)`, so that's still a total of `O(n logn)`

Comment: Of course, this assumes you can compare two words in constant time. If the words can get longer though they do contribute to the runtime as well.

Comment: Comparing two strings is easy as comparing GetHashCode()

Answer (score 2):

Convert both arrays to HashSets and use setequals

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like

```
string[] arr1 = {"cat", "dog", "mouse", "pangolin"};

string[] arr2 = {"dog", "pangolin", "cat", "mouse"};

bool equal = arr1.Except(arr2).Count() == 0 && arr2.Except(arr1).Count() == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a HashSet, assuming there are no duplicates

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "cat", "dog", "mouse", "pangolin" };
string[] arr2 = new string[] { "dog", "pangolin", "cat", "mouse" };

bool result = true;
if (arr1.Length != arr2.Length)
{
    result = false;
}
else
{
    HashSet<string> hash1 = new HashSet<string>(arr1);
    foreach (var s in arr2)
    {
        if (!hash1.Contains(s))
            result = false;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
If you just have four elements it might be faster to skip the HashSet and use arr1.Contains in the comparison. Measure and pick the fastest for your array size.

Comment: It has positive false error, hash doesn't support to do not make unique value for different items

Comment: this is theoretically cheaper, but it might be faster in practice to just say hash1 = HashSet(arr1); hash2 = HashSet(arr2); hash1.SetEquals(hash2)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode :

```
A:array
B:array
C:hashtable

if A.length != B.length then return false;

foreach objA in A
{
H = objA;
if H is not found in C.Keys then
C.add(H as key,1 as initial value);
else
C.Val[H as key]++;
}

foreach objB in B
{
H = objB;
if H is not found in C.Keys then
return false;
else
C.Val[H as key]--;
}

if(C contains non-zero value)
return false;
else
return true;
```