# C#: how do you check lists are the same size & same elements?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, algorithm

There are two lists of string

```
List<string> A;
List<string> B;
```

What is the shortest code you would suggest to check that A.Count == B.Count and each element of A in B and vise versa: every B is in A (A items and B items may have different order).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you don't need to worry about duplicates:

```
bool equal = new HashSet<string>(A).SetEquals(B);
```

If you are concerned about duplicates, that becomes slightly more awkward. This will work, but it's relatively slow:

```
bool equal = A.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEquals(B.OrderBy(x => x));
```

Of course you can make both options more efficient by checking the count first, which is a simple expression. For example:

```
bool equal = (A.Count == B.Count) && new HashSet<string>(A).SetEquals(B);
```

... but you asked for the shortest code :)

Answer (score 2):

```
A.Count == B.Count && new HashSet<string>(A).SetEquals(B);
```

If different frequencies of duplicates are an issue, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153120/whats-the-fastest-way-to-compare-two-arrays-for-equality/).

Answer (score 1):

If you call [Enumerable.Except()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) on the two lists, that will return an `IEnumerable<string>` containing all of the elements that are in one list but not the other. If the count of this is 0, then you know that the two lists are the same.

Comment: `Enumerable.Distinct()` operates on *one* sequence. Did you mean `Enumerable.Except()`?

Comment: @Jon Ah yes I did, thanks for the clarification. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't concerned about duplicates, or you're concerned about duplicates but not overly concerned about performance micro-optimisations, then the various techniques in Jon's answer are definitely the way to go.

If you're concerned about duplicates *and* performance then something like this extension method should do the trick, although it really doesn't meet your "shortest code" criteria!

```
bool hasSameElements = A.HasSameElements(B);

// ...

public static bool HasSameElements<T>(this IList<T> a, IList<T> b)
{
    if (a == b) return true;

    if ((a == null) || (b == null)) return false;

    if (a.Count != b.Count) return false;

    var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(a.Count);
    foreach (string s in a)
    {
        int count;
        dict.TryGetValue(s, out count);
        dict[s] = count + 1;
    }

    foreach (string s in b)
    {
        int count;
        dict.TryGetValue(s, out count);

        if (count < 1) return false;

        dict[s] = count - 1;
    }

    return dict.All(kvp => kvp.Value == 0);
}
```

(Note that this method will return `true` if both sequences are `null`. If that's not the desired behaviour then it's easy enough to add in the extra `null` checks.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = A.Count == B.Count && A.Where(y => B.Contains(y)).Count() == A.Count;
```

Maybe?

Comment: Thank you, I produced something alike but @Jon Skeet put the brilliant code :)

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple loop?

```
private bool IsEqualLists(List<string> A, List<string> B)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < A.Count; i++)
    {
        if(i < B.Count - 1) {
            return false; }
        else 
        {
            if(!String.Equals(A[i], B[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer a groovy linq based way like the answers below A.SequenceEqual is awesome.

Comment: This assumes that both lists are in the same order - they might not be, and even if they were then `SequenceEqual` is, as you say, *a lot* more elegent.

Comment: Ahh yes I actually misread the question about the fact that the different order is *acceptable*. Ok non-linq route would have been A.TrueForAll(a => B.Contains(a));